# CrystalDecisions,.Shared.dll versioning issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

ppI'm trying to deploy an app using Crystal reports, asp.net 3.5 developing in Vs2008.

On my dev boxes, I have CrystalDecisions.Shared 11.5.3300 and 11.5.3700.

the only reference I can add in is to verison 11.5.3300, but the only version deployed on my QA server is 11.5.3700.

I keep getting the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I tried changing the reference to the 11.5.3700 version, but Visual Studio will not do it.

I tried adding assembly references to the web.config pointing to 11.5.3700 but I still get the Error.

I tried adding a non reference specific asembly reference to the web.config still no joy.

Here are the CrystalDecisions dlls on the server that is throwing the error:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.TemplateEngine, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.Audit, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.CachePageServer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.Cms, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.EventServer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.FileServer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.JobServer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.ReportAppServer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.SingleSignOn, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Admin.Wcs, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Auth.secEnterprise, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Auth.secLDAP, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Auth.secWinAD, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Auth.secWindowsNT, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Calendar, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Connection, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Event, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Excel, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.FavoritesFolder, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Folder, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Hyperlink, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.LicenseKey, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.ObjectPackage, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Pdf, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Powerpoint, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Program, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Rtf, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Server, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.ServerGroup, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Shortcut, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Txt, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.User, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.UserGroup, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Word, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Dest.DiskUnmanaged, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Dest.Ftp, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Dest.Smtp, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Integration, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.PluginManager, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.PluginManager, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Shared, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=zh-CHT, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=zh-CHS, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Strings.resources, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Utils.UtcConverter, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Web, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.KeyCode, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize, Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Shared.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.Mobile.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.Mobile.MobileViewerSys.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-cht, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=zh-chs, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=sv, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=pt, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=nl, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ko, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=ja, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=it, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=es, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.resources, Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=de, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, process
```

It's trying to load 11.5.3300.0, which is not there. only 10.5.3700 and 11.5.3700 are there.

Does anyone have any idea how i can get the versions to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. install compatible version of sap crystal reports for VS10
2. remove your old assemblies
3. go to project and add reference of all ddl files of crystal report
4. clen class library....build it then clean solution build it..now run your project properly

if any query contact me on
ubhal.bhushan@gmail.com

Comment: We Worked around it long ago, but you answer looks right, so checkmark for you, if it fail to work for anyone let me know.

Answer (score 3):

"...or one of its dependencies" may be your first clue.  Did you copy the assemblies using gacutil or did you create an installer package as outlined on the BusinessObjects/SAP/whoever owns Crystal this week's website?  CrystalDecisions.Shared has a lot of dependencies and requires a lot of other assemblies to operate...

Can you look in c:\windows\assembly and provide a run-down on what you have in the CrystalDecisions namespace?

Comment: I love the 'whoever owns Crystal this weeks' comment

Comment: I'll get that soonest, but one of the things I've tried since is
uninstalling and reinstalling the Crystal Redistributable.
Shouldn't that have solved the issue if it was missing depenedencies?

When I look at the Gac, I see crystalDecisions.shared 11.5.3700.00
but no 11.5.3300.00 which is the one trying to be loaded. Don't I need to solve that first? or does is automatically map to 3700 and then look for dependencies?

Comment: Ugh, is there a way to get a list of the files and the versions automatically, doing is SLOW.
Thanks,
Eric-

Comment: oops, i meant "doing it by hand is slow".

Comment: Select multiple assemblies and use "copy display name" from the Edit menu.  That should grab the assembly names and the version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  I don't know the cause of the problem, but this is what seemed to make it go away:

1. Started: All Programs > BusinessObjects XI Release 2 > Crystal Reports > Crystal Reports XI Release 2
2. This triggered the loading of some MSI installer repair tool
3. MSI then requested a path to the file: CrystalReports.msi
4. MSI installer then exited
5. Crystal Reports XI Release 2 finished starting
6. Exited Crystal Reports XI Release 2
7. The problem was now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo when I converted my Crystal report 9.0 application to Crystal report 13.0, so to resolve this problem I just imported "CrystalReportsDataDefModelLib" and it worked fine.

I think I just faced this problem because SAP has optimized and moved some functionality to other DLL so the existing is not working. But the older ones are also present in the new DLL reference we just have to find it.